# How to close X command window in SAS program?

Tags: sas

For example, I have a code like this below.

```
DATA _null_ ;
x 'start https://www.google.com/';
RUN ;

DATA _null_ ;
asleep = Sleep(20) ; /* sleep 20 seconds */
RUN ;
```

To run this code, I have to close X command manually, like clicking "X" or type "EXIT",then SAS starts to execute below the code

```
DATA _null_ ;
    asleep = Sleep(20) ; /* sleep 20 seconds */
    RUN ;
```

[image]

how can I close/exit this X command in SAS Code?

Comment: `noxwait` or `noxsync` option. I'm also fairly certain this is answered on here somewhere if you search.  `options noxwait noxsync;`

Comment: I hope you're not actually running that code - there are much better ways to open web pages in SAS :)

Comment: And @Reeza - I couldn't find a duplicate, hence the answer.  (Lots of questions that are answered by this in part, but all of them are DDE and so not as "clean" as this one.)

Comment: Thanks @Joe. Odd part is I remember answering this exact question several times on here :)

Comment: SO search is pretty bad, so who knows, but I couldn't find it in the amount of time that suggested I should just write the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [XWAIT](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=hostwin&docsetTarget=n0xwt90ik8vxdrn13708w6n3nm4o.htm&locale=en) system option controls the behavior of SAS when it spawns an `x` window.

- `XWAIT` (default): requires the user to type EXIT in the console
- `NOXWAIT`: the window closes on its own when it has completed

You may also want to look at the [XSYNC](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=hostwin&docsetTarget=n0dnk0of8vh258n1jcq8iqyjku7f.htm&locale=en) option, which controls whether or not SAS will continue executing other code statements after the `x` invocation without waiting for it to close.